# Alert when percent of total count exceeds threshold

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

**The background**

We need to know when a higher than usual percentage of requests receive responses with status code 500.  Not the raw count, the percent of total.

Web request logs are shipped to Elasticsearch and visualized with Grafana.

Using the [SingleStat Math](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/blackmirror1-singlestat-math-panel) plugin, we created a dashboard that displays the percent of all requests whose status code is 500.

- Query A - count all where status code is 500
- Query B - count all

Query Math: A/B * 100

We even set the threshold in the widget to turn red when it hits 1%.

That was easy.  This, of course, requires someone to watch the dashboard.  What we need is an alert.

**The problem**

How do I create an alert that fires under the same circumstance - i.e. for a given period of time when the number of 500s exceeds 1% of the total number of requests.

I understand Alerts only apply to the graph widget.  So the answer to my question is to create a graph showing the percent of total.

I can add the two queries to the graph as with the SingleStat Math widget, but I don't see how to set the alert reducer to use both, let alone to divide one by the other.

It seems this should be simple: send me an email when that widget turns red.  But how do I do this?

**What I've tried**

- Using [MetaQueries](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/goshposh-metaqueries-datasource) (type: Arithmetic, expression: A/B) but no data appears.
- Dashboard as datasource hopefully to pull the value from the SingleStat Math widget.  This appears only to pull the queries, not the calculation.

Comment: Have you tried using bucket_scripts? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-script-aggregation.html . This can fx be used instead of 'count()' in your alert condition.

Comment: @badaboomskey - yes, this did the trick!  Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

@biscuit314 You can calculate the percentage in the graph panel using the Metaqueries plugin. I have verified this, it works. You just need to get the format of the percentage calculation syntax right and the query with Metaquery datasource needs to be below the queries being used for calculation. That shall make it work.

Comment: I have not been able to get MetaQueries to work.  All examples I've seen refer to a metric within a query by name/alias e.g. A['alias'] / B['name']  But I don't see how to alias a metric with Elasticsearch as datasource.  Alias the query, yes, but A/B doesn't work.

Comment: Grafana provides an alias section right beside the query in the elasticsearch datasource query panel. You should specify your query alias for each query and use that alias in the metaquery arithmetic calculation syntax. For example, if you use alias 'sc500' for query A and 'all' for query B, then your syntax would be A['all']-B['sc500'] in metaquery.

Comment: If you don't provide an alias for the elasticsearch query, then the metric name is to be used in metaquery syntax i.e 'count' in your case, hence, your syntax should be A['Count']-B['Count']. I don't remember if the 'c' in count is required to be in upper/lower case. Do verify that too.

Comment: I appreciate the detailed explanations.  I tried everything (well, clearly everything except what works).  To simplify I created one elasticsearch query and one metaquery.  I tried with the Alias field populated and without.  In the metaquery Expression field I tried A['Count'], A['count'], A[0], A[1].  I tried all of those with A or with the alias.  I tried all of those combinations with math like A['Count']+1   In all permutations I get "No data"

Comment: You should also check if your queries with elasticsearch as the datasource are able to get data in output. They should be receiving data from elasticsearch and it should be displayed in the panel, irrespective of the metaquery query. The output of metaquery should be displayed as a separate series in the panel.

Comment: I tried same, MetaQueries output is there in graph but grafana says it doesn't support data source for alerting.